# Joomla article title to be h4

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I want that Joomla article title is rendered as h4 tag. Currently it is rendered as h2, that is by default.

The only thing I imagine is overriding template in my custom template. I am not sure that this is the right way and I wonder if there is some easier way (some configuration or something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin that let you control header tags in your site without having to override in template.

Named Header Tags and can be found here:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/meta-data/14835

Comment: +1 I did not know about this. Just know about output overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Template overrides are available exactly for such purposes. So it would be the recommended way.
Of course a plugin solution works as well, but may be a bit slower.